# Create bootable SD card

Tags: boot, sd-card

I have a Toshiba Portege M205 tablet.  The hard drive died, so I picked up another one and stuck it in there, with the intent to reinstall Windows XP Tablet.  However, this particular computer did not come with an optical drive in it.  Instead, it has a USB CDRW/DVD drive.  There are only one or two models of Toshiba USB CD drives that are bootable, and the M205 doesn't boot from USB.

Needless to say, my Toshiba CD drive died and I can't boot from it.

One other option I have is to boot from SD card.  I would like to boot into an environment that has USB drivers so I can attach another USB CD drive and install Windows on my tablet.  I've tried using [WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/), but I couldn't get it to work for SD cards.

Anyone know how to make a bootable SD card that has USB drivers?

I'd like to add that the M205 can only recognize up to approx 32 or 64 MB SD cards, so I can't put the install media on the SD card.

Comment: Do you have a floppy drive for that laptop?

Comment: Sd cards have a funky format, see this tool to properly format a SD card....http://www.sdcard.org/consumers/formatter_3/

Comment: nope, no floppy drive.

Comment: thanks for the info about formatting, Moab, but I can't find anything about booting from SD card.

Comment: Are you sure your computer would boot the SD card? Please specify which devices you computer can boot (you will find that in the BIOS setup screen) and among these which ones have "died".

Comment: @user39559: Computer can boot from CD-ROM (attachable via USB, currently dead), SD Card, HDD, Network. Note that I cannot boot from USB, except that it's one of two special Toshiba CD-ROM drives.

Comment: [SliTaz](http://www.slitaz.org/) is 35 MB and has a SD install guide [here](http://doc.slitaz.org/en:guides:sdcard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to Create a Bootable Windows SD Card or Flash Drive](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/create-a-windows-bootable-install-sd-card-or-usb-flash-drive/)

> **Step 1. Partitioning your SD Card**
>
> Start > cmd
>
> diskpart
>
> list disk and then do select disk 2 based on your disk number for your
>   SD Card
>
> [image: list disk]
>
> After selected Clean
>
> create partition primary
>
> select partition 1
>
> active
>
> This step would take some time so be patient
>
> format fs=fat32
>
> assign letter=y
>
> exit
>
> **Step 2. Copying the iso**
>
> Mount the iso using MagicDisc or insert a Windows DVD/CD
>
> Following command copies the bootable disk, here E: is the source disc
>   wher you windows media is Y: is your SD Card
>
> xcopy e:* y:\ /s /e /f
>
> [image: xcopy to copy bootable iso]