# TW700 not booting from USB or microSD

Tags: windows-10, bootable-media

I have changed my Boot Order and moved USB CD, USB HDD, USB FDD to top but still it doesn't boot from USB Thumb drive or the SD Card

### Bootable Media

I have confirmed that both my USB Thumb Drive and SD Card are bootable by using then on another Computer. I used following instructions to create bootable cards

[Create-bootable-sd-card](https://superuser.com/questions/185433/create-bootable-sd-card/1063046#1063046)

i just used Boot Camp to create bootable USB Thumb drive

### My Boot Menu

[image: boot menu]

Comment: I presume since your attempting to install Windows 10, you have verified the media, has the required EFI drivers it otherwise it won't be seen or even listed.  This also assume you have not enabled any sort of compatibility mode, Compatibility Support Module (CSM), or Legacy Mode.  If you are attempting to install Windows 10, Rufus works, and/or the Media Creation Tool itself.

Comment: USB HDD should allow it to boot from a thumbdrive, be sure usb legacy support is enabled in the bios if it exists.

Comment: @Moab i don't see any option to enable or disable Legacy support

Comment: @Ramhound i really don't know to verify EFI drivers i just used the boot camp to burn en_windows_10_enterprise_version_1511_x64_dvd_7224901.iso on a usb drive

Comment: Have you checked for BIOS updates? Unless you have booted from USB on this machine before, you may want to check for an update that might fix this.